# Why I cannot change the pointer (reassign it) in a function?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I'm learning the pointer in the function. When I pass pointer `x` into update(), I found that I cannot let it point to another memory? Why does this happen? Why I cannot let the `x` point to another memory on heap or stack? What should I do if I wanna achieve the goal?

```
void update(int *x){
  int *a;
  a=malloc(sizeof(int));
  x=a;//x is still point to original a rather than memory
      // assigned by malloc()
  }
int main() {
  int a=4;
  int *b =&a;
  printf("%d ",*b);
  update(b);
  printf("%d ",*b);
  return 0;
}
```

Thank you~

Comment: `//x is still point to original` No, at that point `x == a` and they both point to the same memory block allocated by `malloc`.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing the value of a pointer. If you want to have that pointer modified, then you'll need to pass a pointer to the pointer. Is this what you're intending?

```
void update(int **x){
    int *a;
    a = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *x = a;
}
int main() {
    int a = 4;
    int *b = &a;
    printf("%d ", b);
    update(&b);
    printf("%d ", b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah that can let the original `b` point to the memory on heap. But what if I wanna let `x` (the local pointer in update()) point to the new memory?

Comment: In your code `x` will point to the heap, but that will not update the value of `b`

Comment: @MusicalChicken: Like xavc said, your code in the question already does that, but I don't know what the purpose of that function could be, unless you want to return `x`, in which case `update` doesn't need to have a parameter.